# In School 42 project get_next_line, it is ok to submit a function where the user has to manually free memory. Why does this comply with the subject?

Tags: c

In the [subject description](https://github.com/Surfi89/42cursus/blob/main/Subject%20PDFs/01_get_next_line_en.pdf), it is said that:-

`All heap allocated memory space must be properly freed when necessary.`

I thought this meant that, in the main.c, the user must be able to just call *get_next_line* without worrying to free any memory afterwards.  But this is not the case.  Cf. the answers published on

https://github.com/Surfi89/get_next_line/blob/main/get_next_line.c
(main.c commented out at the bottom)
and
https://github.com/n1kito/Get_next_line/blob/main/src/main.c

Why?  What exactly is meant by *properly freed when necessary*?

Just to sketch an idea, in the ajordan code example (first link above), I added an extra function below that saves the user the trouble to having to remember to free memory afterwards:-

```
char    *already_freed_get_next_line(int fd)
{
    char    *line;
    char    *temp;
    int     i;

    line = get_next_line(fd);
    i = 0;
    while (line[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp[i] = line[i];
        i++;        
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    free(line);
    return (temp);
}
```

And also the following two lines in the main.c

```
line = already_freed_get_next_line(fd1);
printf("line: %s", line);
```

Now I am aware that this does *not* compile with the -Werror flag: ‘temp’ is being used uninitialized in this function.  But otherwise it runs okay and saves the user from having to remember to manually free memory afterwards.

So is the answer to my question that it is just *impossible* to create something along the lines of *already_freed_get_next_line* that actually compiles with all the relevant flags?  Hence the correct answers published online have succeeded in freeing all heap memory *"when necessary*"?

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `temp`. You can't assign to `temp[i]`.

Comment: When a function returns dynamically-allocated memory, it becomes the caller's responsibility to free it.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) But the " temp[i] = line[i]" line does run; moreover, isn't strcpy implemented similarly?  (2) I am aware of this, but have always wondered why?  Isn't this placing rather an onerous burden on the user, who has to figure out before hand whether a function has a malloc living inside of it?  I am new to programming in general, so any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means it might actually work sometimes, but it's most definitely a bug. And `temp[i] = line[i];` is most definitely a bug given that `temp` is uninitialized. ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings! I use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors` with gcc.

Comment: Indeed. To clarify @Barmar's comment, you _can_  assign to `temp[i]` but the subsequent behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: I see, so basically -Werror is warning me that using an uninitialized variable leads to undefined behaviour, potentially causing portability problems.  But in what concrete situation would "temp[i] = line[i]" fail or lead to problems?  Grateful for any hints so that I can get a better grip of the issue here.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I will also do more reading and research on my own.

Comment: Re "*causing portability problems*", It's not a portability concern. It means the program might do anything. It can change from machine to machine, but it can also change from run to run on the same machine.

Comment: RE "*But in what concrete situation would "temp[i] = line[i]" fail or lead to problems?*", It's almost impossible for it not to fail and lead to problems. Virtually any value of `temp` will cause problems. For example, on an x86 or x86-64, if the memory used `temp` was `0`, it will cause a protection fault (SIGSEGV).

Comment: The bottom line is that `malloc` allocates memory and *you* have to `free` it when you no longer need it - nothing will get around that.

Comment: @Chris A distinction without a meaningful difference, as far as I'm concerned. Outside some special cases (e.g. you're deliberately trying to cause a buffer overflow for an exploit, or you're taking advantage of an implementation extension), you must not cause undefined behavior. It would be like saying you can commit murder, but it's illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I am aware that this does not compile with the -Werror flag:
> ‘temp’ is being used uninitialized in this function.

The code invokes undefined behaviour¹ because the pointer `temp` was never initialized and has an indeterminate value. It doesn't point to anything meaningful.

> So is the answer to my question that it is just impossible to create
> something along the lines of already_freed_get_next_line?

Yes, there's no way to return a pointer to freed memory and not trigger undefined behaviour.

> But the " temp[i] = line[i]" line does run.

Undefined behaviour doesn't mean that an assertion or a signal would be raised that will crash the program.

> isn't strcpy implemented similarly?

`strcpy()` doesn't deal with memory management; the calling code does. It too would invoke undefined behaviour if it is passed an uninitialized pointer.

> so basically -Werror is warning me that using an uninitialized
> variable leads to undefined behaviour, potentially causing portability
> problems.

Not portability problems per se. See the footnote below.

> Isn't this placing rather an onerous burden on the user, who has to
> figure out before hand whether a function has a malloc living inside
> of it?

I believe not. It's the user's fault if he/she didn't read the function's documentation. Unlike higher level language, C doesn't take care of memory management for you.

> Hence the correct answers published online have succeeded in freeing
> all heap memory "when necessary"?

Yes, they have succeeded in freeing all heap memory after it was no longer needed by calling `free()` in the calling code.

*When a function returns dynamically-allocated memory, it becomes the caller's responsibility to free it.* – Barmar

---

### Footnote:

1 — The C standard defines undefined behaviour as:

> C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §3.4.3 1 undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a non portable or erroneous program construct or
> of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
> requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
> completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
> or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
> terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
> diagnostic message).

Comment: @ikegami It's not initialized *because* they didn't allocate memory for it.